# Paypal appID for adding to application

Tags: android, paypal

I'm working on Paypal integration into my application. I'm done with everything regarding application part and I can execute it with demo key of Paypal for payment. But I still have doubt on one thing. Does the user who hold the paypal account only have to get the appid for application so that the payment will be to his account. Because since I am a developer, can I use different paypal id to make payment to some other account.

Comment: What library are you talking about, the new or the old one?

Comment: Can you also make your question much more clearer? Right now, I do not get your question.

Comment: @Mido: My doubt is. I am a developer and my client don't know how to get the appID, also he don't wan't give his information of paypal account. Can I use my appID to make donation to his account.

Answer (score 0):

The merchant (the one who receives the money) has to use their appID and their email address on the account used to get the appID. You can use your own appID and email address but the money will go into your account.